# How to understand all the tables and their relationships in a database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I came across a database which has around 80 tables, I am new to SQL Server. I need to understand the relationships of all the tables. Typically any database with over a 100 tables will look like a spiderweb; is there any other alternative for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at each part seperately. Pull the tables around until it looks like it has some order. These diagrams are the closest you get to an overview

Comment: Beat the developer up until he explains it to you... For more complex database structures, aligned diagrams should have been made. Unfortunately, often the developerhas this relationship overview only in his head, and it gets never drawn, so now you are stuck with reverse-engineering it. There is no good alternative

Comment: Any specific tool you would suggest to convert an  existing database into a database model.

Comment: What do you mean by "database model"?  Are you referring to database diagrams of some kind? Does the existing database have foreign keys set up?